# Route issue in laravel

Tags: laravel, routes

I have those 2 routes:

```
GET|HEAD  | tournaments/{tournament}/users  | tournaments.{tournament}.users.index  | App\Http\Controllers\TournamentUserController@index | 
POST      | tournaments/{tournament}/users  | tournaments.{tournament}.users.store  | App\Http\Controllers\TournamentUserController@store |
```

I need to call:

```
    $breadcrumbs->push(trans('crud.add_competitors'), route('tournaments.users.index', $tournament->id));
```

But I get an error with:

```
route('tournaments.users.index', $tournament->id)
```

The error is:

```
Route [tournaments.users.index] not defined.
```

What is the way to call this route???

Comment: So I take it `{tournament}` in your route is variable then? In your `routes.php` file does the route look like `Route::get('tournaments/{tournament}/users', 'ControllerName@index')`?

Answer (score 1):

Route names are literal so it should be this:

```
route('tournaments.{tournament}.users.index', $tournament->id)
```

I would recommend changing the name though to this if you can: `tournaments.users.index`. Your route names don't need to have arguments in them. Actually, they can't have arguments in them. Your uri, controller, etc. accepts arguments. Route names are literally just "names" / intuitive descriptions for your routes.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not good to use argument in route name.If you are using this

`route('tournaments.users.index', ['tournament'=>$tournament->id])`

Then, your route must me

```
Route::get('/tournaments/{tournament}/users',array(
   'as'=>'tournaments.users.index',                     
   'uses'=>'TournamentUserController@index' 
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing the concept of named routes in laravel:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#named-routes

Routes in your case becomes:

```
Route::get('tournaments/{tournament}/users', ['as' => 'tournaments.users.index', 'uses' => 'TournamentUserController@index']);
```

Now you can call this route like:

```
route('tournaments.users.index', ['tournament' => $tournament->id]);
```

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score -1):

You use named route but your named route defined as

```
  tournaments.{tournament}.users.index
```

But you call route with

```
 route('tournaments.users.index', $tournament->id)
```

You need to change your route name as tournaments.users.index

Comment: I didn't understand. Isn't it what I'm doing?

Comment: You need to open your routes.php file and change its name from 'tournaments.{tournament}.users.index' into 'tournaments.users.index' or if you do'nt change your routes.php then you must call it route('tournaments.{tournament}.users.index', $tournament->id);

Answer (score -1):

Hey just if you have two controller just use like this

```
Route::resource('tournaments','TournamentController');
Route::resource('users','UserController');
```

this will give you the routes what you ask :)